# I have a discord bot written in Python that I use for certain commands. Is it possible to restrict the use of the commands to a certain role?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

So basically, me and some other guys are working on a bot for a discord server. The bot is used to send images, dm links and such. Due to an issue we have faced we decided that we need to restrict the use of commands. So far, the administration ones are based on the user having the delete message permission.
What I would like to know is if it would be possible to restrict the use of commands to a certain role/roles.

```
 @bot.command(pass_context=True)
 async def givefood(ctx, user: discord.User):
       if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.manage_messages:
          await bot.say("Check direct messages <a:okedokey:518350515726319635>")
```

Comment: I would advice you to add some code into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: Did that, thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can restrict the use of certain commands to a certain role in Discord.py.
Here's how:

```
if "rolename" in [role.name for role in message.author.roles]:
    command()
else:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Sorry, you don't have the permission to do that.")
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to do the reverse though? Like if someone has a certain role he can't use commands?

Comment: Also as an update, I seem to get a undefined variable in the message.author.roles line.

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Keyblade Master","Foretellers")
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
```

thats all i needed to make my command just for roles i want, and

```
@purge.error
async def purge_error(error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, CheckFailure):
        await ctx.channel.send("Looks like you don't have permission for that!")
```

this stopped the check failure runtime error but doesnt send anything to the channel, still won't let lower roles use these commands though so this should help